# Keep receiving error: revert// when trying to store a variable

Tags: solidity, remix

currently i am attempting to add an asset, so that it is added to storage but i keep receiving error revert

```
function addAsset(
  address payable _owner,
  string calldata _name,
  uint _valueUSD,
  uint _cap,
  uint _annualizedROI,
  uint _projectedValueUSD,
  uint _timeframeMonths,
  uint _valuePerTokenCents
) external {
  VTToken token = new VTToken(
    _owner,
    address(stableToken),
    _name,
    _valueUSD,
    _cap,
    _annualizedROI,
    _projectedValueUSD,
    _timeframeMonths,
    _valuePerTokenCents
  );
```

Error:

VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to change anything, if you read the error it states add payable IF you send value, but this function is simply adding to storage, no value must be sent.

Comment: can you share you contract?

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the error, prefix the constructor with **payable** keyword.